# How to Retrieve Json List Filtered in Redis?

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

Let's say I have a Redis Model as follows:

```
 public class ExampleModel
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     public ExampleEnum? Example { get; set; }
     public Example2Enum Example2 { get; set; }

     public string Description { get; set; }
 }
```

I store Example Model as Json List in Redis:

```
var json = _redis.JSON();

await json.SetAsync("example:1", "$", exampleList);
```

Now I need to retrieve a list of examples based on **ExampleEnum** and **Example2Enum**

SQL alternative would be:

```
SELECT * FROM examples WHERE ExampleEnum = 1 AND Eample2Enum = 2;
```

So far everybody suggests storing examples one by one, do some Indexing, and then search by them. But I don't really need that. I want to store examples in a list in one Key/Value in Redis. And I want to perform filtered request.

**Also I need to perform OFFSET FETCH logic, (SKIP, TAKE in Ef Core).**

```
.Skip(10).Take(10).ToListAsync()
```

How do I do this?

My stack is:
***.Net 8, NRedisStack***

Comment: Redis doesn't support querying JSON structures as you assumed. You need to query list first, then filter it, which means **OFFSET FETCH** is applied after list is retrieved and loaded into memory. That's why everybody suggest so.